# In JavaFX, how can I bind two listview's so their selectedIndex is always the same?

Tags: listview, binding, javafx, selectedindex

I have two (or more) ListView's that are side by side. I need them to act as one so the selected index of each is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :), maybe.

```
var lv1 = ListView {
}
var lv2 = ListView {
}

var onSync = false;    

var sel1 = bind lv1.selectedIndex on replace {
    if (not onSync) {
        onSync = true;
        lv2.select(sel1);
        onSync = false;
    }
}
var sel2 = bind lv2.selectedIndex on replace {
    if (not onSync) {
        onSync = true;
        lv1.select(sel2);
        onSync = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll give that a try, thanks for your answer! Another thing however, I've noticed that in JavaFX 1.2 it doesn't appear to be possible to manipulate the scrollbar, so I could potentially select the 100th index, but I wouldn't be able to see it. (To the best of my knowledge.) Thanks!

Comment: This definitely worked, thanks a lot! Only issue is the scrollbar!

Answer (score 0):

"bind with inverse" seems to be an option:

```
var a;
var b = bind a with inverse;
```

works only for simple expressions. anything more complex will generate a warning/error.

Except that it isn't because of ListView's selectedIndex is public-read (thaks for the correction).

You will have to do it like this:

```
var lv1 = ListView {
}
var lv2 = ListView {
}
var sel1 = bind lv1.selectedIndex on replace {
    lv2.select(sel1);
}
var sel2 = bind lv2.selectedIndex on replace {
    lv1.select(sel1);
}
```

You also may want to add some ifs here and there to avoid extra select() calls.

Comment: How can I set the selectedIndex though? It appears they don't have write access according to the API. So I'm not sure how to implement it. Sorry! Thanks!

Comment: Honza, this is not working. selectedIndex is RO property only. And your next suggestion makes infinite loop. (better said, causes StackOverflowError)